# Reading a .xlsx file in java

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to upload an Excel 2007 (`.xlsx`) file and then read its data using Struts 2 using the code below:

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(upload);
Workbook wb_xssf;
Sheet sheet = null; 
wb_xssf = new XSSFWorkbook(inp);// ERROR Line 4
sheet = wb_xssf.getSheetAt(0);
```

However, it's throwing an error on line 4 (indicated above). Can anybody help solve this issue?

I am using the following JARs:

- dom4j 1.1
- xmlbean 2.3.0
- poi 3.9 jars

Interceptor for file upload in struts.xml

```
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
    <param name="allowedTypes"> 
        application/vnd.ms-excel,application/x-msexcel,application/ms-      excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    </param>
    <param name="maximumSize">
        1073741824
    </param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

This is the stacktrace for the exception:

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
        org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
        org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    root cause

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
        org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:154)
        org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
        org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:54)
        org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:82)
        org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:267)
        org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
        org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:204)
        com.livic.RateAnalysis.biz.SteelAction.saveUploadExcel(SteelAction.java:544)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
        org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
        org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    root cause

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:154)
        org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
        org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:54)
        org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:82)
        org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:267)
        org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
        org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:204)
        com.livic.RateAnalysis.biz.SteelAction.saveUploadExcel(SteelAction.java:544)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
        org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
        org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
        org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
```

Comment: Try `WorkbookFactory.create()` rather than hardcoding the class.

Comment: i tried this but exception in WorkbookFactory.create() method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual (**root cause**) of your exception is on this line.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
```

Download DOM4J and put the library into your classpath and compile/build your code.

Comment: finally i solved problem.problem was in jar dependency.I changed DOM4J1.1 to DOM4j 1.6 .